# Identify specific PNG format

Tags: images, png, imagemagick

How can I tell, ideally with an Imagemagick `identify` command, whether a particular PNG is PNG32, PNG24 or PNG8?

The `%z` or `%[depth]` gives the sample depth (not the pixel depth), which is always 8 or 16 regardless of PNG format, and `%m` or `%[magick]` just reports `PNG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions (6.6.9-2, of 2011-03-30, and later), "identify -verbose" outputs IHDR.bit_depth and IHDR.color_type:

> identify -verbose g1.png | grep IHDR
>
> png:IHDR.bit_depth       : 1
>
> png:IHDR.color_type      : 0 (Grayscale)

or

> identify -verbose png24.png | grep IHDR
>
> png:IHDR.bit_depth       : 8
>
> png:IHDR.color_type      : 2 (Truecolor)

or

> identify -verbose png64.png | grep IHDR
>
> png:IHDR.bit_depth       : 16
>
> png:IHDR.color_type      : 6 (RGBA)

Comment: In what version was it introduced?

Comment: @OrangeDog I added the feature to IM version 6.6.9-2, 2011-03-30

Answer (score 2):

To complete Kyle's answer, seems you have to use something like this (tested with IM 6.8.4):

```
#!/bin/sh

type=$(identify -verbose $1 | sed -n "s/^.*png:IHDR.color_type.*(\(.*\))$/\1/p")

case "$type" in
Indexed)
   depth=8
   ;;
Truecolor)
   depth=24
   ;;
RGBA)
   depth=32
   ;;
esac

echo $depth
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, -verbose outputs the IHDR.color_type value, more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Color_depth).